# \b not behaving as expected with Regex/Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use re.findall() find all the occurrences of the names of weekdays. It works when I exclude the `\b`, but not when I include them. This works:

```
any_week_day_long = "([Mm]onday|[Tt]uesday|[Ww]ednesday|[Tt]hursday|[Ff]riday|[Ss]aturday|[Ss]unday)"
match = re.findall(any_week_day_long, "Monday is a great day of the week. Tuesday is pretty good, but Wednesday has it beat.")
```

but this does not:

```
any_week_day_long = "\b([Mm]onday|[Tt]uesday|[Ww]ednesday|[Tt]hursday|[Ff]riday|[Ss]aturday|[Ss]unday)\b"
match = re.findall(any_week_day_long, "Monday is a great day of the week. Tuesday is pretty good, but Wednesday has it beat.")
```

It seems to me like it should find Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday just fine with the `\b`, but when I `print` match, it's just an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `\b` try: `\\b`

```
any_week_day_long = "\\b([Mm]onday|[Tt]uesday|[Ww]ednesday|[Tt]hursday|[Ff]riday|[Ss]aturday|[Ss]unday)\\b"
match = re.findall(any_week_day_long, "Monday is a great day of the week. Tuesday is pretty good, but Wednesday has it beat.")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even achieve the same using [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals). Instead of doing something like `[M|m]`, it's much better use the re.IGNORECASE flag for the same. A much cleaner way to do the same.

```
any_week_day_long = r'\b(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day\b'
match = re.findall(any_week_day_long, "Monday is a great day of the week. Tuesday is pretty good, but Wednesday has it beat.")
```

Output:

```
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
```